# И снова сравнительный оборот 2

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот

Нужны ли здесь какие-либо запятые? Возможно, две запятые вокруг *как средство раздувания смога* или только одна, если иметь в виду дополнительное обстоятельственное значение *будучи средством для раздувания смога*?

По своему назначению как средство раздувания смога она была антиэкологична и отвергнута.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложение необходимо перестроить.

(1) Как заметил ddbug, неверно говорить "раздувать смог".

Вариант замены: "средство для борьбы со смогом"

(2) Неверно выражена мысль: "По своему назначению... она была антиэкологична". 
Ведь не хотите же вы сказать, что она была предназначена быть антиэкологичной.

Вариант замены: "По своему назначению она была средством борьбы со смогом, но оказалась  антиэкологичной."

(3) В качестве однородных членов предложения выступают слова, выражающие  неоднородные понятия ("она была антиэкологична и отвергнута"). Причем "антиэкологична" относится к "по своему назначению", а "отвергнута" - нет. Вариант замены: "была антиэкологична, и поэтому была отвергнута".

Окончательный вариант:

**По своему назначению она была средством борьбы со смогом, но оказалась  антиэкологичной, и поэтому была отвергнута.**

P.S. А сравнительного оборота, заявленного в вопросе, нет даже в исходном варианте. Ничего здесь не сравнивается.

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развернутый ответ! Действительно, предложение не совсем грамотное, зато есть неповторимый авторский стиль... )))

Answer (score 2):

По одному предложению трудно оценить всю ситуацию, но мне кажется, что предложение нужно отредактировать, например:

**В  качестве средства для раздувания смога она не стала применяться по причине антиэкологичности.**

Так я поняла смысл сказанного и попробовала передать его своими словами.

Если вернуться к исходному предложению и ничего не менять, то оборот нужно или обособить с пояснительным значением (а именно), или не обособлять с определительным значением (какому назначению), тогда запятые не нужны.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Склоняюсь к выделению... Здесь это не обособленное определение, а сравнительный оборот...

Comment: Смог не "раздувают".